# The checkpoint always fails on the same subtask

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am completely desperate to find solutions. I have a program that works well but after some time, it can be either a few days (maybe few hours) checkpoints failed after timeout.

Backpressure effect doesn't dettect, data balance's ok, jobManager out (like and taskmanager out) is ok.

I tried restarting my job many times, but I always get a problem with operator subTask_id: 9.

Update:
When I increased the parallelism from 40 to 60, the first 18 hours the job worked well, then began to have problems with the checkpoints (subTask_id: 13,18) and after 30 failed checkpoints there was a backpressure effect.

Today I set a parallelism equals 10. No effect

Please look at my screenshots below.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you checked for data skew, or perhaps there's a NULL in a key somewhere that causes a disproportionate amount of data to be handled by one specific task?

Comment: @MartijnVisser null key is not possible because I check the value of the future key in the filters